# Returning Json from an MVC controller that extends Apicontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to return a Json string from an MVC controller in a WebAPI application, but am unable to use `return Json(...` because the class being used extends `ApiController` and not `Controller` (I believe).

Is there an alternative method to do what I'm trying to do (e.g. return a different type)?  Or a workaround?

This is my controller code:

```
public class SocialController : ApiController 
{
    public ActionResult Get(SocialRequest request) // or JsonResult?
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsontest = js.Serialize(request); // just serializing back and forth for testing

        return Json(jsontest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is **"System.Web.Helpers.Json is a type but is used like a variable."**

I've found the following related SO question but it hasn't solved it for me, if anyone can elaborate I'd really appreciate it (and dish out the rep points):
[Why Json() Function is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088736/why-json-function-is-unknown)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Asp.net Web Api you don't have ActionResults anymore. You simply return the object you need. The framework converts the object to the proper response (json, xml or other types)

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers(SocialRequest request)
{
    return _applicationsService.GetUserss(request);
}
```